# Is the differential equation $(x+2y)\mathrm{d}x + (2x+y)\mathrm{d}y = 0$ exact?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Take the differential equation $$(x+2y)\mathrm{d}x + (2x+y)\mathrm{d}y = 0$$ Let $M(x, y) = x + 2y$ and $N(x, y) = 2x + y$. Then, $$\dfrac{\partial M}{\partial y} = 2 \quad \mathrm{and} \quad \dfrac{\partial N}{\partial x} =2 $$ shows that the differential equation is exact. But when I solve for the general solution for the differential equation, I get two different answers (depending on the variable I use to derive the solution).

We know that $$\mathrm{d}F = \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}\mathrm{d}x + \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}\mathrm{d}y$$ Then, deriving our solution with respect to the $x$ variable, $$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x} = x + 2y \Rightarrow F = \dfrac{x^{2}}{2} + 2xy + \Phi(y)$$ From the equation above, $$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y} = 2y + \Phi'(y) = 2x + y$$ $$\Rightarrow \Phi'(y) = 2x - y \Rightarrow \Phi(y) = 2xy - \dfrac{y^{2}}{2} + c$$ $$\Rightarrow F = \dfrac{x^{2}}{2} - \dfrac{y^{2}}{2} + 4xy + c$$

Now, we derive our solution with respect to the $y$ variable, $$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y} = 2x + y \Rightarrow F = \dfrac{y^{2}}{2} + 2xy + \Phi(x)$$ From the equation above, $$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x} = 2x + \Phi'(x) = x + 2y$$ $$\Rightarrow \Phi'(x) = 2y - x \Rightarrow \Phi(x) = 2xy - \dfrac{x^{2}}{2} + c$$ $$\Rightarrow F = -\dfrac{x^{2}}{2} + \dfrac{y^{2}}{2} + 4xy + c$$

Showing that the two approaches give different results. Does this mean that this equation is not exact, or is there an error in my attempt at deriving the general solution?

Thanks.

Comment: You made a mistake, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=2x+\phi'\left(y\right)$

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja I see. Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't even notice that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in both the computations of $\partial F/\partial y$ and $\partial F/\partial x$ from $F$. The correct computation gives $$F(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{2}+2xy+\Phi(y) \implies \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = 2x + \Phi'(y).$$
Then the identity $2x+y=\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=2x+\Phi'(y)$ gives $\Phi'(y)=y$.

Note that you can detect this type of error when you reach an equation of the form $\Phi'(y)=2x-y$. This should have been impossible, since exactness of the differential equation guaranteed that there was a well defined function $\Phi$ depending only on the variable $y$.

Comment: Thanks @EeroHakavuori. I didn't even notice that. And yes, I noticed that the equation $\Phi'(y) = 2x - y$ seemed a bit odd, but didn't realize it was due to a mistake I made. Thanks again.